# Azure Function blob trigger not starting

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-blob-trigger

I have an azure function with blob trigger. Function should trigger once a day but it works sometimes. I found that is function is not awake when file arrives to path used as trigger, it doesn't launch and file is not processed. If I go to portal and refresh the function, it start working and processes all queued files.
Is there a way to make the function triggers without "refreshing" it?
Function code is written in python and it is created in azure using azure devops pipeline.
I attach `host.json` configuration for more details:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true
      }
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:02",
      "visibilityTimeout" : "00:00:30",
      "batchSize": 8,
      "maxDequeueCount": 5,
      "newBatchThreshold": 4,
      "messageEncoding": "base64"
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.3.0, 4.0.0)"
  },
  "functionTimeout": "-1",
  "retry": {
    "strategy": "fixedDelay",
    "maxRetryCount": 0,
    "delayInterval": "00:00:05"
  }
    
}
```

Below you can find function.json file with trigger details

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "inStr",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "container/path_to_file/{name}",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is part of the code of python function, file **init**.py

```
def main(in_str):
    uri = in_str.uri
    split_uri = uri.replace("//", "/").split("/")
    source_bucket = split_uri[2]
    source_key = '/'.join(split_uri[3:])
    source_directory = '/'.join(split_uri[3:-1])
    file_name = source_key.split('/')[-1]
    print(f"File name is {file_name}")
```

Comment: It does not look like a blob trigger...are you sure you pasted the right file ?

Comment: Azure function for Blob trigger in Python , [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python), notice the `bindings` section in function.json, see the reference for [bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-input?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python)

Comment: Hi, I had passed only host.json file, the configuration of app function. I have edit the post and pass function.json file with trigger configuration.

Comment: Share the code fragments of the trigger function

Comment: Your python function need not do all these string splits, parsing etc. The function gets a `InputStream` as input argument, `in_str.name` gives you the name of the blob file that just got added to the storage container. See MS doc [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger).

Comment: Refer this [Microsoft Document](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/blob-trigger-function-does-not-fire-unless-you-visit-the-portal/ba-p/807948) for Blob Trigger Function does not fire unless you visit the portal.

Comment: Thanks for answers. 
RajkumarPalnati-MT, I see the link but I can't change the storage and I tried to launch the function with EventGrid trigger but we have thousands of files to process and EventGrid is too slow, so we have to rollback to blob trigger